# Populating ${SRCS} from CMakeLists.txt in subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I currently define a `${SRCS}` variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` file in my projects root directory, listing every source file required for my executable:

```
SET (SRCS main.cpp
          dir1/file1.cpp
          dir1/file2.cpp
          dir2/file3.cpp
          dir2/file4.cpp)
```

How can I distribute this list across the `CMakeLists.txt` files in each of the subdirectories? That is:

```
CMakeLists.txt
    Adds main.cpp to SRCS and subdirectories dir1 and dir2

dir1/CMakeLists.txt
    Adds file1.cpp, file2.cpp to SRCS

dir2/CMakeLists.txt
    Adds file3.cpp, file4.cpp to SRCS
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's best to hide all the details of setting up the variable `SRCS` in a CMake [macro](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:macro). The macro can then be called in all the project CMake list files to add sources.

In the `CMakeLists.txt` in the project root folder, add the following macro definition:

```
macro (add_sources)
    file (RELATIVE_PATH _relPath "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    foreach (_src ${ARGN})
        if (_relPath)
            list (APPEND SRCS "${_relPath}/${_src}")
        else()
            list (APPEND SRCS "${_src}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
    if (_relPath)
        # propagate SRCS to parent directory
        set (SRCS ${SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endmacro()

add_sources(main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)

message(STATUS "${SRCS}")
```

The macro first computes the path of the source file relative to the project root for each argument. If the macro is invoked from inside a project sub directory the new value of the variable SRCS needs to be propagated to the parent folder by using the [PARENT_SCOPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:set) option.

In the sub directories, you can simply add a macro call, e.g. in `dir1/CMakeLists.txt` add:

```
add_sources(file1.cpp file2.cpp)
```

And in `dir2/CMakeLists.txt` add:

```
add_sources(file3.cpp file4.cpp)
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing out-of-box to build a library with nested subdirectories??

Comment: @James see the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921695/how-can-i-build-a-c-project-with-multiple-interdependent-subdirectories)

Comment: I've tried your macro and it works as presented if I have a top directory and one level of subdirectories. It however does not work for more levels of nesting, for example with ., ./sub1 and ./sub1/sub2. In that case sub2 sees the SRCS correctly, sub1 also, but the top folder (.) sees only its own sources and the ones in sub1, without sub2... It turns out that I need to first do add_subdirectory() and only then call add_sources() - this way it works. Is there any way to avoid such behaviour?

Comment: If you have more than one level of nested directories, use a [global property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:set_property) instead of a CMake variable.

Answer (score 2):

In dir1/CMakeLists.txt put this:

`set(SRCS ${SRCS} file1.cpp PARENT_SCOPE)`

If that wouldn't work, the only solution is to

`set(DIR1_SRCS "file1.cpp" PARENT_SCOPE)`

and then in ./CMakeLists.txt

`set(SRCS ${DIR1_SRCS} ${DIR2_SRCS})`

Answer (score 2):

A similar macro like the one suggested by sakra was posted on the CMake mailing list by Michael Wild [1]. It uses global properties instead of propagating a variable upwards.

[1] http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-March/035992.html