# CMake - Getting list of source/header files for various subprojects

Tags: c, linux, cmake

## Background

I have a large [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) project that makes use of dozens of subprojects: some from in-house code bases, and some third-party projects which also use `CMake`.

To ensure common compiler options, I setup a macro in `CMake` called `CreateDevFlags` which is run in only the in-house sub-projects own `CMakeLists` file as the first line of code to execute. This makes sure that I don't break the compiler flags, output directory overrides, etc, for third-party projects, and all of the code I wrote myself is built with identical options.

Additionally, each sub project has a simple block of code along the lines of the following to define the source files to be compiled:

```
file(GLOB subproject_1A_SRC
    "src/*.c"
)

file(GLOB subproject_1A_INC
    "inc/*.h"
)

file(GLOB subproject_2B_SRC
    "src/*.c"
"extra_src/*.c"
)

file(GLOB subproject_2B_INC
    "inc/*.h"
"extra_details_inc/*.h"
)
```

---

## Goal

I would like to add a sanity-check custom rule/function to the "master" `CMakeLists` file at the project root which runs all of the code for in-house subprojects through a code sanitizer (checks newlines, enforces style rules, etc).

---

## Question

Is there a trivial way to have all "special" (ie: in-house) subprojects append their own source files to a "master" list of source (`.c`) and header (`.h`) files (possibly via the macro I created)? I realize I could manually create this list in the master `CMakeLists` file, but then I'd be duplicating efforts, and code maintainers would have to modify code in two places with this in effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end. [the following approach solved my problem:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049226/1022889)

```
set(DIR1_SRCS "file1.cpp" PARENT_SCOPE)
```

and then in ./CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SRCS ${DIR1_SRCS} ${DIR2_SRCS})
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation would be to have a list called FILE_TRACKER defined at top scope for your project. Then, you could do something like

```
# Create local list to append to
set(LOCAL_LIST ${FILE_TRACKER})

# Append all of your source files, from your local source
foreach(SRC_FILE ${subproject_1A_SRC})
    list(APPEND LOCAL_LIST ${SRC_FILE})
endforeach()

# Append to the upper macro (note: was initially set with FILE_TRACKER)
set(FILE_TRACKER ${LOCAL_LIST} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

The developers would only have to add their source to the one list, and the macro at the top level will be updated with the files.

Comment: Does all of this go in the top-level CMake file?

Comment: I put the first two lines in the top level project, and the remaining lines inside sub projects, but the parent-level project never sees the list get updated (confirmed with `message` commands in my top-level CMakeLists.txt file).

Comment: It seems you solved your problem, but the way that was supposed to work was to have the snippet in each of your lower level CMakeLists.txt, with the upper macro set in your root.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't examine header files.  Instead use include dirs for the paths to the header files.  If you do this you will automatically get the depends working without having to track them yourself.

Your sanitizer should be able to parse the actual code to find and read the included headers.