Trying to list files in sub directory using CMake
I am trying to list files in subdirectory with a specific pattern using CMake...
function(ListFilesInSubmodule directory_path pattern)
    if(DEFINED WIN32)
        execute_process(COMMAND powershell -c 'Get-ChildItem -Path "${directory_path}" -Recurse -Filter "${pattern}" -File | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName }'
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Files
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
        )
    else()
        execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "find '${directory_path}' -type f -name '${pattern}'"
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE _Files
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
        )
    endif()

    if(NOT _Files)
            message(STATUS "No files found matching pattern '${pattern}' in '${directory_path}'.")
    else()
        string(REPLACE "\n" ";" _FilesList ${_Files})
        foreach(_file IN LISTS _FilesList)
            if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_file}")
                set(PLUGIN_STRUCTURES
                    ${PLUGIN_STRUCTURES}
                    "${_file}"
                    PARENT_SCOPE
                )
                message(STATUS "File is found '${_file}'.")
            else()
                message(WARNING "File is possibly not found '${_file}'.")
            endif()
        endforeach()
    endif()
endfunction()

i tried the function like this
ListFilesInSubmodule("libs/subhook" "*.c")
ListFilesInSubmodule("libs/subhook" "*.h")

message(STATUS "PLUGIN_STRUCTURES : ${PLUGIN_STRUCTURES}")

and it almost works but the target variable is set to the last file's name only not all of them as expected (for each function call)
I tried to set a separate variable like
    else()
        string(REPLACE "\n" ";" _FilesList ${_Files})
        foreach(_file IN LISTS _FilesList)
            if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_file}")
                set(_Temp ${_Temp} "${_file}")
                message(STATUS "File is found '${_file}'.")
            else()
                message(WARNING "File is possibly not found '${_file}'.")
            endif()
        endforeach()
    endif()
    set(PLUGIN_STRUCTURES
        ${_Temp}
        PARENT_SCOPE
    )

but it didn't work either...

Bad idea. It will not discover new files. Take a look at a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090926/cmake-generate-list-of-source-files-without-glob

Why do you want to split *.c and *.h? Targets need both .c and .h in sources. Look at aux_source_directory

@3CxEZiVlQ some kind of sorting for debugging purposes

Being called with PARENT_SCOPE flag, set command set the variable in the parent scope only, it doesn't change the variable in the current scope. So,  when you dereference the variable with ${PLUGIN_STRUCTURES} on the next iteration, the variable is still empty. As for the second approach, you don't describe what exactly is not working. But according to your implementation, the second call to ListFilesInSubmodule function will overwrite the variable PLUGIN_STRUCTURES being set in the first call to that function.

@Tsyvarev >As for the second approach, you don't describe what exactly is not working.

the final result of the PLUGIN_STRUCTURES variable is the last file's name only not all files while debugging messages show all files



second call to ListFilesInSubmodule function will overwrite the variable PLUGIN_STRUCTURES being set in the first call to that function. - no it is not... this part is working


and without PARENT_SCOPE it doesn't share the variable outside the function

So much code. Why not use file(GLOB_RECURSE? only not all of them as Using global variables is trouble. Why not pass variable name as argument and use it like other cmake functions do? ListFilesInSubmodule(var "libs/subhook" "*.c")?
